# C# Unable To Change Components Of Form From Another Class

Tags: c#, forms

Before I start, I'd like to say that I have looked for an answer for this over the internet for quite a while, and unable to come to a solution. I know how to solve this, but it doesn't want to work.

Here's what I know: Assuming that I have a label and another class, if I want to manipulate the label I need to create an instance of the form that has the label, call the method of the new class with the form, and then call the method from within the form class that changes the label. This is what I have.

This is from the form class

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Question steve = new Question(1, 1, "nothing", new string[] {});
        steve.Show(new Form1(), "I win");
    }

    public void ChangeLabel(string s)
    {
        this.lblTest.Text = s;
    }
```

And this is the Question class

```
    public void Show (Form1 f, string str)
    {
        f.ChangeLabel(str);
    }
```

Syntax-wise this is correct, and when running the debugger lblTest.Text did equal "I win", but there were no visual changes on the form.

P.S. I am in high school and still learning C#, so if I made any mistakes in my explanation or the code, please point them out. Also, disregard the Question constructor, it's useless right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No ! you don't need to create new instance of the form.**

You must pass the current instance using `this` keyword:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Question steve = new Question(1, 1, "nothing", new string[] {});
    steve.Show(this, "I win");    //change it
}
```

Comment: I KNEW it was something to do with creating the form instance! Thank you for solving this.

Comment: For future reference, was I changing the label of a different form? I want to know so that I don't do this again in the future.

Comment: Yes. Actually you created another form by `new Form1()`.